# How can I get AngularJS go to another page onclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJS routing, which is changing the template when I select a link. However, for the last page, I have a link that I want to go to another internal HTML page and not load a template view again. How can I do this?

So far I have tried a few options but here is what I have now.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

  .when("/page-eight", {
    templateUrl : "views/page-eight.html",
    controller: 'primaryController'
  }) 
  .otherwise({
    templateUrl : "views/start.html"
  });
}]);
```

The above routing work, but as I have a link in my `page-eight.html` template as shown below, how can I force it to go to an internal page instead?

```
<a ng-href="internal-page.html" class="btn-solid">Go to Internal Page</a>
```

It seems that by clicking on the link above, this is connected to the `'otherwise'` part of my route set up. Therefore, this doesn't go to my `internal-page.html` but loads in my `start.html`, not what I want.

Comment: What about adding the internal-page to the routing?

Comment: Because it is not using, and is different than the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you add target="_self" it will bypass the router.

Also, your server side route handler needs to serve up the correct "non-SPA" content for that specific page, depending how you have it set up.